# Hash Tables: Ransom Note (time limit exceeds)

Tags: python, data-structures, hashtable

Harold is a kidnapper who wrote a ransom note, but now he is worried it will be traced back to him through his handwriting. He found a magazine and wants to know if he can cut out whole words from it and use them to create an untraceable replica of his ransom note. The words in his note are case-sensitive and he must use only whole words available in the magazine. He cannot use substrings or concatenation to create the words he needs.

Given the words in the magazine and the words in the ransom note, print Yes if he can replicate his ransom note exactly using whole words from the magazine; otherwise, print No.

Example
= "attack at dawn"  = "Attack at dawn"

The magazine has all the right words, but there is a case mismatch. The answer is .

Function Description

Complete the checkMagazine function in the editor below. It must print  if the note can be formed using the magazine, or .

checkMagazine has the following parameters:

string magazine[m]: the words in the magazine
string note[n]: the words in the ransom note
Prints

string: either  or , no return value is expected
Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers,  and , the numbers of words in the  and the , respectively.
The second line contains  space-separated strings, each .
The third line contains  space-separated strings, each .

Constraints

.
Each word consists of English alphabetic letters (i.e.,  to  and  to ).
Sample Input 0

6 4
give me one grand today night
give one grand today
Sample Output 0

Yes
Sample Input 1

6 5
two times three is not four
two times two is four
Sample Output 1

No
Explanation 1

'two' only occurs once in the magazine.

Sample Input 2

7 4
ive got a lovely bunch of coconuts
ive got some coconuts
Sample Output 2

No

Explanation 2

Harold's magazine is missing the word .

```
# Complete the checkMagazine function below.
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    hash_table = [[] for _ in range(5)]
    test=0
    for a in magazine:
        length=len(a)
        key=(length-1)%5
        hash_table[key].append(a)
    for a in note:
        key=(len(a)-1)%5
        
        if a not in hash_table[key]:
            test=1
            break
        else:
            hash_table[key].remove(a)
    if test==1:
        print("No")
    else:
        print("Yes")
```

my time limit exceeded for case 16 and 17. please help how to improve it

Comment: There are gaps in your question. Like here: *The answer is .* -- The answer is? You might also want to make your question a bit more readable. Currently, it is a wall of text.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement your own hash table, instead of using one provided by python (e.g. `dict`, `Counter`, `defaultdict`)?  Even if you had to do that, `key=(length-1)%5` means all N-character words hash to the same bucket - you want to try to distribute words across a large number of buckets (normally roughly as many as there are words).  If you don't know how to write a better string hash function, google that first.

Answer (score 2):

##### Introducing Python Counters

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): A Counter is a `dict` subclass for counting `hashable` objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

```py
from collections import Counter

def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    magazine_counter = Counter(magazine)
    note_counter = Counter(note)
    return "Yes" if magazine_counter & note_counter == note_counter else "No"
```

The logical `&` between the two counters will give you the minimum of corresponding counts. Comparing the result with the `note` is what you want.